# Best way to apply Index Match excel function on a dataframe with million combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have an excel sheet with 1270 rows and 20138 columns. Rows consist of pincodes and column city name. I want to fill second sheet based on intersection of row and column cell value from first sheet.

I've tried making a dictionary for first sheet but since rows x column makes million of combination, iterating through data frame is very slow. Tried using Index Match function in excel but it can't handle such volume of data.

Looking for alternative approach for the problem where I can do this operation in shortest time using python or pandas

[image].

Comment: Excel sheet can hold up to [16384 columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Please provide a sample input - (it does not have to be all the rows / columns), and the expected output. Please provide this information, at least the input, as text so that people can copy-paste

Comment: I want to fill values in 2nd sheet ex( For city ABHANPUR and Pincode 524302) by searching them from 1st sheet. 1st sheet has "REST OF INDIA" for this combination, that is the cell value I want in my 2nd sheet